# Split polygon multiple line nodes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, polygon, filling, nodes

I have a landmask derived from Landsat, transformed into polygons. Due to the raster origin, there are a lot of 4 line nodes (see picture), creating "holes" of unmasked area within the polygons. 
[image: A no-value area is created by surround polygon. At one point the polygon is connected in only one node, creating a closure.]
*Picture. Black polygon/raster land area, white unmasked/no value area.*

The small contained white quadrats are a problem, while the uncontained must remain unmasked/no-value. I can not use these black polygons, since (fetchR) in R then complains due to "TopologyException /.../ Ring Self-intersection". I estimate the nodes to be at least a hundred. Can anyone think of

A. a workaround, fixing these nodes automatically, e.g. by at each node connected by >2 lines create two juxtaposed nodes OR filling these areas (either as polygon/raster).

B. a quick way to identify these nodes for manual fixing.

Comment: In raster calculator convert no data to say 1. Convert to polygons. Select one that share boundary with original. Merge, dissolve.

Comment: That is one way to fix them one by one. Very labor intensive, but might use that as a way out. Thanks.

Comment: It will take a minute to fix all of them. Select ONES that share boundary with original. I do it all the time to fix stray cells for hundreds of subcatchments

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'Eliminate Polygon Part' tool.  You would use the 'contained_only' option.  You can also specify area or percentage parameters for the removal condition.

Here are the docs:  [Eliminate Polygon Part](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/eliminate-polygon-part.htm)